# How to transition an element that does not exist on the DOM yet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Now I have code like this

```
  {data.inventoryOn === true ? (
      <div className="inventoryOptions flex__container-v">
        <Link to="listofmedicines" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <div className="inventoryoption">
            <p className="p__poppins">List Of Medicines</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
        <Link to="medicinegroups" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <div className="inventoryoption">
            <p className="p__poppins">Medicines Groups</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ) : null}
    {data.spaceBelow ? <div className="space" /> : null}
```

as you might have noticed for the code to appear it depends on some state value to be true.

My question is **how do I get it to appear smoother**. I cant transition it because I don't know the property like background or color or something else. And the **content is not hidden** for me to transition using opacity since it is completely not available when the state value is not true.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `opacity: 0` when adding it. After you add the element, use `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 or 1, then set the opacity to 1 in the callback.

Comment: Or you can just add a CSS property to a particular container class like .property {
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

Comment: This is also a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist to use conditional rendering , you can use css animation and  onAnimationEnd prop according to react, there is an implementation in this [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-brook-wwiwf?file=/src/App.js)